# Is it common for FIGO stage 3 ovarian cancer to have involvement of lymph nodes along greater curvature of the stomach?

Tags: cancer, stomach

I'm a medical student and I'm doing research on cancer. My thesis is about lymph nodes and I'm stumped with the question above. I can't find much literature pertaining to the current topic and would like some help or advice on the above.

Comment: Have you tried checking any large cancer registries for primary data about staging and lymph node involvement? You could answer the question yourself.